# Finding Maximal Clique in O(n^2) Time?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, clique

I was making a research about Clique Problem and algorithms. Then I saw [that](https://iq.opengenus.org/greedy-approach-to-find-single-maximal-clique/). As this article says, we can find maximal clique in O(n^2) time complexity. Did I misunderstand something or this is a proof that P=NP?

Comment: "Maximal" is different from "the maximum." A maximal clique is simply one that cannot be extended.

Comment: This article describes how to find a random maximal clique for a random vertex in`O(n^2)` where n is the number of vertices in the clique.

Comment: @גלעדברקן But doesn't 'clique' mean 'complete graph'?

Comment: No, in this case it means “complete sub graph”.  As in every vertex in the clique connects to every other one *in the clique*.

Comment: @RBarryYoung So 'maximum clique' means 'complete sub-graph with maximum edges' and 'maximal clique' means 'complete sub-graph'. And real 'problem' of clique problem is finding 'maximum clique'. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, The article clearly describes the problem that it is solving.  It is *not* trying to find the largest clique in the graph. It is finding a random clique that can’t be extended (i.e., “maximal”).

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for your time. :)